# How to launch the android web browser and navigate to a specific position in page

Tags: android, browser

In android application, sending ACTION_VIEW intent with URL will launch the system web browser to open the web page, and is it possible to set the start position of the web page (or scroll position).
For example, an android cloud client can receive a URL with its current page position from a user's PC browser and let the user continue reading from where they left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. I've checked sources of Browser, you can set in intent only url, initial zoom level and parameter to create new tab.